# A random floating ad is always on top

Tags: ads

In the following image, you can see a floating ad and it looks like an average ad by Google. Problem is, it's always on top. In the image, you can see it over my Settings app.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

I did not install any new apps on to my device (OnePlus One running CM12s - Android 5.0.2), and the single ad keeps popping up randomly in different positions on the screen. (Since today morning.)

Following is a screenshot of the webpage that opens up, when I select 'opt out'.

[image: IMG:]

From where did this come from, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Go in to Settings -> Apps, and then swipe across to 'Running'. If there are any unfamiliar apps there, tap on them and choose Force Stop and press OK. If the floating banner goes away, you've found the culprit.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an adblocker? It is rather easy to nuke them off  instead of hunting down the source.  Also, is the device rooted?

Comment: Related http://android.stackexchange.com/a/122715/119358

Answer (score 2):

You've got some kind of adware. Check your running apps and stop any apps that are unfamiliar-looking. Be sure to checked cached processes as well.