# Android suddenly pops up ad

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, ads

Suddenly my Android always pops up this ad that always in that position, even sometimes a video ad, when I wake my phone from sleep. Anyone has idea?

When I open the recent used app, it displays the correct recent used app.

I have tried uninstall my but no luck:

> - FF Record Keeper
> - 3rd party theme

[image]

Comment: Are you using a 3rd-party homescreen/launcher? When did this start happening?

Comment: I use 3rd party theme from Samsung store. I don't think there will be ad because of that? It was yesterday start happening when I went back to my country, even I was still inside plane turned my device on.

Comment: I don't know (I don't have Samsung device), you may want to check that on the Store. Anyway, it means that you're using a Samsung device on default TouchWiz launcher, but using 3rd-party theme? You may want to [determine which app is drawing on top of other apps](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127769/determine-which-app-is-drawing-on-top-of-other-apps), or if it's okay for you, just uninstall that theme and see if it still happens.

Comment: I don't suspect ad to be the root cause because I have used it for some months. Anyway I have uninstalled my latest installed game `FFRK` and will update here later.

Comment: still the same..

Comment: Please check my updated post...

Comment: Perhaps [this related question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124880/why-does-this-ad-keep-showing-up-below-my-notification-bar-and-how-do-i-stop-it?rq=1) might help you. Otherwise, try [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/122705/how-to-track-down-an-app-that-shows-ads-on-smartphone-screen/)

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to try and find which applications are running by using a program that displays your current processes. One of those will be the adware. You could also try and install some android anti-adware blocker, or even cut out the banner with an image editing program, make an image search and find which program or advertisiment the image matches, then you will know which program it is and you can find instructions how to remove it.

If you install [termux](https://termux.com/) you can run the command `ps -al|more` and paste the output, then we will see which processes are running.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion of app name that can display my current process?

Comment: @Rendy We can try and install a "task manager". I need one myself. Or can try with termux and run the `ps -al` and see.

Comment: @Rendy Just open *Settings › Apps* and check the "running" tab. Focus on the apps you've installed last, those are the most likely candidates. Anything you've side-loaded (installed from a different place than Google Play)? This app would violate Playstore rules (by showing ads *outside* the app and not making the relation clear), so if you've installed it from there I recommend to report it to Google.

Comment: Well my last installed app is `FF Record Keeper`. I have tried uninstall it and will update here whether ad still pops up or not.

Comment: @Programmer400 termux is very hard to be understood reading its log from mobile..

Comment: Please check my updated post...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why and how, but the ads gone by itself in 1 week. I still believe this is a malware though.